# Pickup horadric staff after dropping it in different difficulty

Tags: diablo-ii

I picked up the horadric staff parts and created the staff in hell. Afterwards I created a game in nighmare difficulty and dropped the staff to pick an item up I wanted to quickly sell. After selling it I was not able to pick up the satff again. When clicking on it it just jumped up like I just dropped it.

Is it possible to somehow pickup the staff parts or the complete staff after dropping it in a different difficulty than in which you obtained it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you screwed yourself.

You have to go back to Hell difficulty and make the staff again.

This is also true for everything quest related. Mephi's soulstone, Forge hammer, Charsi's hammer...etc.

If you have completed the quest in a previous difficulty and go back to that difficulty, you'll be unable to pick up a completed quest's item. It's just a flaw in the game that was never fixed. The game doesn't remember what difficulty items are assigned to.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are still many unfixed bugs. Check this link below for details. Even though I know many of these (and maybe I won't classify every single one here as a bug), I was surprised by how many issues there are present here: https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20743204621